# Abstract valued port error for LQR - Drake

Tags: drake

I'm trying to linearize the dynamics of a "multibodyscenegraph" for an LQR controller. When I call the `Linearize` function, I'm getting an error saying `The specified input port is abstract-valued, but FirstOrderTaylorApproximation only supports vector-valued input ports.` I've tried passing non-default values for the input port index, but still getting the same error. What's the meaning behind the abstract value error? Thanks

```
`def run_lqr_control(q0, Q, R):
    #q0 is the initial state
    builder = DiagramBuilder()
    plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, 1e-3)
    parser = Parser(plant)
    ConfigureParser(parser)
    parser.AddModelsFromUrl(
        "package://underactuated/models/littledog/LittleDog.urdf"
    )
    parser.AddModelsFromUrl(
        "package://underactuated/models/littledog/ground.urdf"
    )
    plant.Finalize()
        
    context = plant.CreateDefaultContext()

    context.SetDiscreteState(q0)
    plant.get_actuation_input_port().FixValue(context, np.zeros(12))
    linear = Linearize(plant, context)

    A = linear.A() 
    B = linear.B()

    K, S = DiscreteTimeLinearQuadraticRegulator(A, B, Q, R)

    MatrixGain(-K )
    controller = builder.AddSystem(MatrixGain(-K))
    controller.set_name("LQR Controller")

    builder.Connect(
        plant.get_state_output_port(), controller.get_input_port_estimated_state()
    )
    builder.Connect(
        controller.get_output_port(), plant.get_actuation_input_port()
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have good news and bad news.  The good news, is that making the call to `Linearize` is simple enough -- but you need to pass the diagram, not the plant.

```
from pydrake.all import DiagramBuilder, AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph, Parser, Linearize
from underactuated import ConfigureParser
import numpy as np

builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, 1e-3)
parser = Parser(plant)
ConfigureParser(parser)
parser.AddModelsFromUrl(
    "package://underactuated/models/littledog/LittleDog.urdf"
)
parser.AddModelsFromUrl(
    "package://underactuated/models/littledog/ground.urdf"
)
plant.Finalize()
builder.ExportInput(plant.get_actuation_input_port(), "actuation")
diagram = builder.Build()

context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()

#context.SetDiscreteState(q0)
diagram.get_input_port().FixValue(context, np.zeros(12))
linear = Linearize(diagram, context)
```

The bad news is that you'll still get the error

```
Penetration queries between shapes 'Capsule' and 'Box' are not supported for scalar type drake::AutoDiffXd
```

Which is reasonable.  You are trying to linearize through the contact mechanics (this is supported in some cases, but not all).  Normally one would not use LQR to stabilize a legged robot, but use e.g. the quadratic programming version of inverse dynamics, as referenced from https://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/humanoids.html#section4 .